# fix regex not to detect numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex, string

I use this custom regex to detect words in a string (js)

```
/[a-zA-Z_\u00C0-\u017F]+|\w+/g
```

what do I have to change so that numbers won't get matched?

Example, In the following string

```
"hello, 5 this 6is :a 2021 test"
```

the following words will get matched

```
["hello", "5", "this", "6is", "a", "2021", "test"]
```

but I want this

```
["hello", "this", "is", "a", "test"]
```

Comment: It’s because of the `\w`, it accepts a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _

Comment: Just use this: `/[a-zA-Z_\u00C0-\u017F]+/g`

Comment: You should remove everything from the vertical bar to the end.  \w matches [A-Za-z0-9_] and you already do everything except the numbers on the left.

Comment: I am new to SO and not sure why some questions get answered in comments. Shouldn't these only be for seeking clarification or additional info?

Answer (score 0):

The comments found a solution:

remove the \w !

final result

```
/[a-zA-Z_\u00C0-\u017F]+/g
```

Thank you, Hamza Jadid, Tim biegeleisen and Chris Maurer.